# How to show domain.com/subdomain instead of subdomain.domain.com

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I don't want to redirect user from `subdomain.domain.com` to `domain.com/subdomain` but I want to read the data from `/home/mysite/public_html/domain.com` but to have the URL seems it is reading from sub-directory. How can I achieve this?

I have tried `.htaccess` file but it just redirects but I want it to be only shown in URL.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/subdomain/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

I'm using WordPress. Why don't I move from subdomain to sub-directory? because I'm using WordPress and Laravel next to each other. That one had lots of error that blocked my way completely not to continue. So I have it in subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Try to redirect 301 all pages from domain.com to subdomain.com, all wordpress instalation.